# Android keyboard Enter/Next Button handler

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget, android-view, android-keypad

In my Android application I have 4 `EditText`s laid out like this:

```
E11   E12

E21   E22
```

When I'm writing in E11 and tap Enter or TAB, it focus E21 as a default Android behaviour. How can I make it go to E12 instead?

Answer (score 3):

You would want to look at the following xml attributes :

- android:nextFocusUp
- android:nextFocusLeft
- android:nextFocusDown
- android:nextFocusRight

More information and sample tutorial can be found at this [link](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-user-interface-design-the-basics-of-control-focus-order/).

Comment: Very good article. :)